# Print time update it by 1 sec in the same time with getting user input under the time line

Tags: c

I want to make a digital clock in C with the time is update real time by 1 second. And i want to put input under the digital clock line. I'm using windows. And here is what i've tried before

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void display_time(){
    time_t s, val = 1;
    struct tm* current_time;

    while(1){
        s = time(NULL);
        current_time = localtime(&s);
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            current_time->tm_hour,
            current_time->tm_min,
            current_time->tm_sec);
        if(current_time->tm_sec == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    display_time();
    printf("\nEnter number for i: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I want the output like this, but the digital clock still updated by 1 second. But i don't know how to perform it.

```
HH:MM:SS
Enter number for i: //example 10
10
```

Comment: It sounds like a task not a question.  You need an interrupt handler or thread for the 2nd thread of control.  Not sure what you use on Windows, but on Linux you may want to use something like (n)curses to manage the input/output.

Comment: mb, im using mingw in Windows as my compiler